# Coded UI Test multilingual combobox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I have a multilingual web application. I have recorded test cases with coded ui test builder for English language. I have a issue about combobox. It gives an error when I play test case for French language. Because it records that selecteditem value for english. How to solve this issue? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When you record an action that sets a combo box value, you generally end up with both a method that executes the action, and a "Params" property where you can set a value to select.

For example, if you made a method called `SelectFoo`, you'd have a property called `SelectFooParams`, which exposes a value for the combo box.

This allows you to record one action and then reuse it for multiple situations, instead of making one recording for every possible value of the combo box.